# Configure a server inside LAN

Tags: networking, routes

I'm currently working on my group voice chatting program. This is my plan:

> 1. Build up a server on 192.168.1.125. Listen to port 3490 and forward it to the router.
> 2. Clients connect to the server and get the user IP list(Whenever a client connects to the server, its IP address is recorded by the
>      server)
> 3. Clients communicate with each other using UDP multicast(is this ever possible across the router?).

But now I'm running into troubles. If a client inside the LAN, e.g. 192.168.1.120, connects to the server, it's taken down as 192.168.1.120, which won't work for clients from WAN.

I'm wondering if there is any way to convert the LAN IP to public IP? (this might have something to do with the router, I think)

Thanks.

Comment: A router usually routes all client packets through one ip address so you probably can't. You could host it remotely though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to be prepared for the case where direct client-to-client communication fails. Relaying through the server or NAT traversal/penetration may be necessary. Significant expertise is required to do this correctly.

Comment: Maybe I should learn something about NAT traversal. Does this requires a high performance server? Mine is a Raspberry Pi...